# Force between an uncharged and a charged point object

Tags: electricity, charge

Imagine that we have two small orbs, one of which is positively charged with charge Q. 
These orbs are placed at some distance R.
Will the Coulomb's Law work in this scenerio, even though only one of them is charged? Thus, will the charged orb attract the uncharged one with force
$$F=k\frac{Q^2}{R^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neutral objects are to charged objects due to an induced charge separation.  If the objects are "point objects" as per the title of you question rather than just "small" then there is no room for this induced charge separation and you can not use Coulombs's law to predict an attraction.

Comment: What if these objects were very small, would it then be possible to apply Coulomb's Law?

Comment: Very small like dust particles - sure.  How small are you thinking?

Comment: Does it work for bigger objects - just like balloons - as well?
Another thing - this is quite counterintutitive why the uncharged object is treated as if it had a charge equal to the second object (Q^2)

Comment: I've amended my answer to include your balloon question.

Comment: An important point is missing from this answer:  the force due to polarization of the object *does not obey Coulomb's Law*.  So the answer to the OP's question is *no*.

Comment: The cited reference to "equal charges" applies to a grounded conductor.  It does not apply to this situation.   The charge on the originally-neutral object remains zero.

Comment: Point taken, I've rolled back my edit.